# MVC 4 OWIN application using session store for Cookie authentication results in Thread.CurrentPrincipal != HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, wif

In an OWIN MVC application, I am trying to preserve the BootstrapContext.SecurityToken between requests to allow for creating an ActAs token for federation.

By default the Cookie serialization tries to preserve the BootstrapContext.Token (string form) and ignores the BootstrapContext.SecurityToken (decoded token), this sort of makes sense, avoiding the exposure of the decoded token?

I have therefore tried to use the CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore to preserve the whole BootstrapContext server side. This (sort of) works but with the problem as described below!

Background:

I have lifted the AspNetAuthSessionStore implementation from the sandbox code in the Katana source repository [http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/] which functions as expected saving and restoring the ticket to the HttpContext.Session.

I also lifted the following extension code:

```
public static class AspNetSessionExtensions {
    public static IAppBuilder RequireAspNetSession(this IAppBuilder app) {
        app.Use((context, next) => {
            // Depending on the handler the request gets mapped to, session might not be enabled. Force it on.
            HttpContextBase httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
            httpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Required);
            return next();
        });
        // SetSessionStateBehavior must be called before AcquireState
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
        return app;
    }

    public static IAppBuilder UseAspNetAuthSession(this IAppBuilder app) {
        return app.UseAspNetAuthSession(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    }

    public static IAppBuilder UseAspNetAuthSession(this IAppBuilder app, CookieAuthenticationOptions options) {
        app.RequireAspNetSession();
        options.SessionStore = new AspNetAuthSessionStore();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options, PipelineStage.PreHandlerExecute);
        return app;
    }
}
```

and use the registration functions in my OWIN Startup.

Problem:

In my MVC 4 target action I check the following:

```
 var ctxtuser = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
 var claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
```

With the straight cookie implementation (no session store):

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {});
```

the two principals are the same and are the expected value (but without the BootstrapContext content!).

If I simply try to add the Session store to this implementation:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
    SessionStore = new AspNetAuthSessionStore()
 });
```

it fails due to there being no session to store into! Presumably because we aren't allowed a session at Authenticate stage.

If I use the registration from the extension above:

```
app.UseAspNetAuthSession(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
 });
```

version then the code functions almost as expected except that the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is not equal to the HttpContext.User by the time it hits my action. The context user is my claims principle but the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is set to an annonymous WindowsPrincipal.

I have debugged through the code and the claims principal is being applied to both the thread and the context in:

```
 Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.SetServerUser
```

But somehow the Thread version gets set back to the annonymous Windows user before hitting my action??

I assume this has something to do with the specific pipeling stage setting in

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options, PipelineStage.PreHandlerExecute);
```

as opposed to the default value (PipelineStage.Authenticate) used when I request

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()...
```

I am wondering if the default code setting the principal at the Authenticate stage makes it 'Stick' as the one ASP.Net wants to use, waiting until PreHandlerExecute is too late?

But can't see how to fix this.

What am I doing wrong?